# Xamarin Forms certain parts of System APIs not available

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use this method:
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Type.GetInterfaces()/
like this:

```
public MainPage(Type type) {
    if (type.GetInterfaces().contains("Form")) {
        // go on
```

But my Xamarin Studio does not recognize the GetInterfaces method, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a PCL Xamarin Forms project. I suggest you read more about that [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/) or watch some of the helpful videos around the internet (like [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Sharing-Code-Across-iOS-Android-and-Windows) one, which talks about different PCL Profiles) but basically and PCL project attempts to allow many of the common APIs available on all platforms. This means that if a certain platform does not support `GetInterfaces()` or if the Forms team has not implemented that API yet, it will not be available to your from the Forms project.

The nice thing about Xamarin Forms is that you can still access all native APIs if you need to. To do this you would create an interface and use Xamarin Forms Dependency Service ([link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/)) which would probably allow you to access that API from your Forms project.

If you need an example of how to do that, just let me know.